# Self-Referential Many-to-Many Relationship with Association Proxy in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

I'm trying to create a Self-Referential Many-to-Many Relationship. The example outlined in the [SQLAlchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#self-referential-many-to-many-relationship) works great. Here are the models I created:

```
from sqlalchemy import Integer, ForeignKey, String, Column, Table
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

Base = declarative_base()

Table('NodeToNode', Base.metadata,
    Column('leftNodeId', Integer, ForeignKey('Node.id'), primary_key=True),
    Column('rightNodeId', Integer, ForeignKey('Node.id'), primary_key=True)
)

class Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Node'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    label = Column(String)

    rightNodes = relationship('Node',
        secondary='NodeToNode',
        primaryjoin='Node.id==NodeToNode.c.leftNodeId',
        secondaryjoin='Node.id==NodeToNode.c.rightNodeId',
        backref='leftNodes'
    )
```

And the script for adding data in:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///practice.sqlite3')
session = Session(bind=engine)

nodes = [
    Node(label='A'),
    Node(label='B'),
    Node(label='C'),
    Node(label='D'),
    Node(label='E'),
]

nodes[0].rightNodes = [nodes[1], nodes[3], nodes[2]]
nodes[0].leftNodes = [nodes[4]]

session.add_all(nodes)
session.commit()
```

I want to add a column to the association table so I'd assume I need to convert the association table to its own class:

```
class NodeToNode(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'NodeToNode'
    leftNodeId = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Node.id', onupdate='CASCADE'), primary_key=True)
    rightNodeId = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Node.id', onupdate='CASCADE'), primary_key=True)
    sortOrder = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
```

This, however, results in the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Class <class 'models.node.NodeToNode'> does not have a mapped column named 'c'
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I think the string `’NodeToNode’` is being evaluated as the class, not the table. Can you change the table name?

Comment: That did it! I changed the class name to `Node2Node` and kept the tablename as `'NodeToNode'` and it worked. Much appreciated. If you write the solution below I'll accept the answer.